# Custom Template for wordpress cpt plugin

Tags: plugins, custom-post-types, posts

I am creating a wp custom post type plugin. Which supports the custom meta datas as well.Now my question is i have to create a archive page with custom template file. I have added the appropriate function for archive page and as well as single page. Single.php file work fine whereas archive.php is not working. here is my funcitons

```
add_filter('template_include', 'testimonial_archive');
function testimonial_archive( $template )
{

$post_types = array('astestimonial');
 if ( is_post_type_archive( $post_types ) && ! file_exists( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/testimonial_archive.php' ) )
    $template = dirname(__FILE__) . '/list-testimonial.php';
 if ( is_singular( $post_types ) && ! file_exists( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/single-testimonial.php' ) )
    $template = dirname(__FILE__) . '/single-testimonial.php';
return $template;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The file `testimonial_archive.php` is not a valid WP template if you don't define a custom way to use that file. The expected name is `cpt-archive.php`, in your case `astestimonial-archive.php`. Also, instead of using `file_exists`, you should use [`locate_template()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/locate_template) to take adventage of template hierarchy and compatibility with child and parent themes.

```
add_filter('template_include', 'testimonial_archive');
function testimonial_archive( $template ) {

    $post_types = array('astestimonial');

    if ( is_post_type_archive( $post_types ) && locate_template('atestimonial-archive.php' ) == '' ) {
        $template = dirname(__FILE__) . '/list-testimonial.php';
    }

    if ( is_singular( $post_types ) && locate_template( 'single-testimonial.php' ) == '' ) {
        $template = dirname(__FILE__) . '/single-testimonial.php';
    }

    return $template;

}
```